# Python print text in a field on the site

Tags: python, python-requests

how to insert text on this site? And push the button? Is it possible to do this with requests ?
https://www.cachesleuth.com/scytale.html

Comment: This is definitely possible. However, it seems much easier to implement the cipher yourself manually.

Comment: You can also use selenium, such a robot can be easily made with selenium